# need regex expression to avoid " \n " character

Tags: python, regex

I want to apply regex to the below string in python Where i only want to capture    Model Number : 123. I tried the below regex but it didn't fetch me the result.

```
string = """Model Number : 123 
            Serial Number : 456"""
model_number = re.findall(r'(?s)Model Number:.*?\n',string)
```

Output is as follows     Model Number : 123\n   How can i avoid \n at the end of the output?

Comment: Use `m` flag and use `$` instead of matching `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the DOTALL `(?s)` inline modifier to avoid matching a newline char with `.`, add `\s*` after `Number` and use `.*` instead of `.*?\n`:

```
r'Model Number\s*:.*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEpjuf/1)

Here, `Model Number` will match a literal substring, `\s*` will match 0+ whitespaces, `:` will match a colon and `.*` will match  0 or more chars *other than line break chars*.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/TapVvv):

```
import re
s = """Model Number : 123
            Serial Number : 456"""
model_number = re.findall(r'Model Number\s*:.*',s)
print(model_number) # => ['Model Number : 123']
```

If you need to extract just the number use

```
r'Model Number\s*:\s*(\d+)'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEpjuf/2) and [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/tbOUr0).

Here, `(\d+)` will capture 1 or more digits and `re.findall` will only return these digits. Or, use it with `re.search` and once the match data object is obtained, grab it with `match.group(1)`.

**NOTE**: If the string appears at the start of the string, use `re.match`. Or add `^` at the start of the pattern and use `re.M` flag (or add `(?m)` at the start of the pattern).

Comment: When i used the solution i got the blank output .I applied it as model_number = re.findall(r'Model Number\s*:\s+(\d+)',string). Please help me trouble shoot this

Comment: In the string there are spaces between : and the following digits.

Comment: @NewB   I added two demos, https://ideone.com/tbOUr0 and https://ideone.com/TapVvv. Note you asked to get rid of the newline, and the first solution does it. The second one goes further and extracts the digits.

Comment: If the model number is alphanumeric , say "Model Number = X123", how can i capture that too?

Comment: @NewB Replace `\d` with `[A-Za-z0-9]` or `\w`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEpjuf/3).

Comment: Here in this example can i use re.match instead of findall? if yes, please explain how?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strip()` function

```
model_number.strip()
```

this will remove all white spaces